# splitting nsstring and putting into tableview

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsarray, xcode4.3

I am trying to split the string into parts and insert into a table how should i do it?

I got an error for splitting of the array which is: -[__NSArrayI componentsSeparatedByString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a421e0

```
NSArray *BusRoute = alightDesc;
int i;
int count = [BusRoute count];
for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
{  
    NSDictionary *dic = [BusRoute objectAtIndex: i];
    NSDictionary *STEPS = [dic valueForKey:@"STEPS"];            
    NSString *AlightDesc = [STEPS valueForKey:@"AlightDesc"];
    NSLog(@"AlightDesc = %@", AlightDesc);

    NSArray *aDescArray = [AlightDesc componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    NSLog(@"aDescArray = %@", aDescArray);
}
```

This is the string which I'm splitting, i got it from the NSLog

```
AlightDesc = (
"Block1",
"Block2",
"Block3"
)
```

please help I'm stuck thanks.

Comment: your `AlightDesc` contains array, its an array. not string. thats why it thrown an exception

Comment: reading your question, you dont need to split your data, you can just display them in your table   `[AlightDesc objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]`   and also, `NSArray *AlightDesc = [STEPS valueForKey:@"AlightDesc"];`   instead of `NSString`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objective C is not a strongly typed language. All you know for sure about `[STEPS valueForKey:@"AlightDesc"]` is that it will return an object (of type `id`). When you wrote `NSString *AlightDesc = [STEPS valueForKey:@"AlightDesc"]` the compiler did not complain because `NSString *` is a valid object type. Unfortunately there is a logic error in your code so that what was actually stored under the key `@"AlightDesc"` is an `NSArray`. As others have mentioned, `NSArray` does not respond to `componentsSeparatedByString:` so you get an error at runtime.

The easy fix for this is to correct your logic: Either store an `NSString` in the first place or treat what you get out as an `NSArray`. As @janusfidel mentioned you can use an `NSArray` perfectly well in a table by using `objectAtIndex:` to get the string for the entry you want.

In some more complicated cases you may not know what you will be getting out of a dictionary for a particular key. In that case in Objective C you can just ask the object:

```
id anObject = [STEPS valueForKey:@"AlightDesc"];
if ([anObject isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    NSString *aString = (NSString *)anObject;
    // Treat as a string ...
} else if ([anObject isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    // Object is an array ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your NSString *AlightDesc should look like this

```
 NSString *AlightDesc = "Block1,Block2,Block3";
 NSArray *aDescArray = [AlightDesc componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

If your string is what you say it is

```
 AlightDesc = ("Block1","Block2","Block3");
```

then your string is the problem because it's already broken up.